# Vue js detect whenver img tag is created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

i am trying to change all the host names in images to a new domain. I have created a directive but then i realized that i can't apply that to content created by WYSIWYG editor. Is there any way to detect any image tag being rendered at the moment? Even for dynamic images. Or if there's a way to apply my custom directive to all the images on the page even when they are being fetched from the database as post content.
This is my custom directive, i am also on Nuxt.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.directive('image', {
    bind: function(el, binding, vnode){
        if(el.src){
            let parse = new URL(el.src);
            //url processing and stuff
        }else{
            if(binding.expression == 'post'){
                el.src = process.env.backendURL + '/storage/posts/default.png';
            }
        }
        console.error(el.src);
    }
})
```

Comment: You can try using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Researched a bit and created a couple of functions inside default.vue which is the main layout file.

```
  const targetNode = document;

        const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

        const setDefaultImg = el => {
            if (el.dataset.imageType == "user") {
            } else {
                el.src = process.env.backendURL + "/storage/posts/default.png";
            }
        };

        const setImageHref = el => {
            if (el.src) {
                let parse = new URL(el.src);
                if (parse.hostname === "newinfo.am") {
                    let backend = new URL(process.env.backendURL);
                    parse.hostname = backend.hostname;
                }

                if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
                    parse.protocol = "http";
                }

                el.src = parse.href;
            } else {
                setDefaultImg(el);
            }
        };

        const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
            mutationsList.forEach(function(mutation) {
                [].slice.call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function(addedNode) {
                    if (addedNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                        addedNode.getElementsByTagName("img").forEach(el => {
                            
                            el.addEventListener("error", event => {
                                setImageHref(el);
                                setDefaultImg(event.target);
                            });
                        });
                    } else if (addedNode instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
                        
                        addedNode.addEventListener("error", event => {
                            setImageHref(addedNode);
                            setDefaultImg(event.target);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        };

        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Works fine so far.